# who changed the value of "params[:tab]"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In one `erb` file called `x.html.erb`, I am confused by the following  little snippet code:

```
  <% params[:tab] |= "Excursion" %>
  <% availableModels.each do |modelName| %>
    <% if modelName == "Excursion" %>
      <li class="<%= params[:tab]=='excursions' ? 'active':''%>">
        <a id="excursions_tab" href="#tabExcursions" data-toggle="tab"> Excursions
        </a>
      </li>
    <% elsif modelName == "Workshop" %>
      <li class="<%= params[:tab]=='workshops' ? 'active':''%>">
        <a id="workshops_tab" href="#tabWorkshops" data-toggle="tab">Workshop
        </a>
      </li>
    <% end %>
```

I found that I can not figure out how `params[:tab]` is changed such as from `params[:tab] = 'excursions'`to `params[:tab] = 'workshops'`, or vice versa, or said who changes the value of `params[:tab]` when I toggle one tab `Excursion` or `Workshop` the corresponding html:

```
<li class="active">
   <div id="tab_excursions"> ...</div>
</li>
<li class>
   <div id="tab_resources"> ... </div>
</li>
```

or

```
<li class>
    <div id="tab_excursions"> ...</div>
</li>
<li class="active">
   <div id="tab_resources"> ... </div>
</li>
```

For finding the answer, I tried to change `params[:tab]` into `params[:tabx]` and found it also worked fine.  And from `<%= params[:tab]=='excursions' ? 'active':''%>`, this must be relative to some one `rails`'s magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The params[:tab] does not change after it is created. This is part of the rails stub that performs its logic on page load to assist with creating the  markup. The only way we can guarantee where params[:tab] hash has been defined with the current code is at,

```
params[:tab] |= "Excursion"
```

|= assigns params[:tab] to "Excursion" if it has not already been set. With my current view params[:tab] will always equal "Excursion". If either "excursion" or "workshop" show up as active on page load then this hash is being set earlier than this snippet.

What you have in your elements is the data-toggle attribute which groups those two items under the same parent node (I believe). Bootstrap has a Javascript function within it that then listens to your click on either of those elements and then toggles between the two accordingly.

In short, this is a Bootstrap, JS functionality. Check this out : http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs, look for toggleable tabs

--

Determining which tab is initially set to active is based on the params[:tab] value. After that, whichever tab you click on will be set to active by bootstraps JS and CSS and is describable by the link I provided

Comment: Your link did not explain about `params`, Whether I can understand that  the current data-toggle attribute value (here `tab`) determines the value of `params[:tab]`?

Comment: Your link did not explain about `params`, Whether I can understand that  the current data-toggle attribute value (here `tab`) determines the value of `params[:tab]`? I thought your answer again and made sure It is not relative to data-toggle because it works fine even if I changed all `params[:tab]` into `params[:tabsssss]`

Comment: Does your question refer to params[:tab] showing up in controller as a changed value?

Comment: Determining which tab is initially set to active is based on the params[:tab] value. After that, whichever tab you click on will be set to active by bootstraps JS and CSS and is describable by the link I provided

Comment: Thank you for your patient! I agree with you, but the value `active` in  `<li class="active">` or `<li class>` is not determined by `params[:tab]`?

Comment: @@Mohammad, Thank you! I finally understood it through the last your comment, ! Whether you can append the last comment to your answer, thank you !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77566/discussion-between-abelard20008-and-mohammad-bashir).